# Re-referencing a large number of functions in python

Tags: python, decorator, fb-hydra

I have a file `functional.py` which defines a number of useful functions. For each function, I want to create an *alias* that when called will give a reference to a function. Something like this:

`foo/functional.py`

```
def fun1(a):
    return a

def fun2(a):
    return a+1

...
```

`foo/__init__.py`

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction  
from . import functional

for (name, fun) in getmembers(functional, isfunction):
    dun = lambda f=fun: f
    globals()[name] = dun
```

```
>> bar.fun1()(1)
>> 1
>> bar.fun2()(1)
>> 2
```

I can get the functions from `functional.py` using `inspect` and dynamically define a new set of functions that are fit for my purpose.

But why? you might ask... I am using a configuration manager [Hydra](https://hydra.cc/) where one can instantiate objects by specifying the fully qualified name. I want to make use of the functions in `functional.py` in the config and have hydra pass a reference to the function when creating an object that uses the function (more details can be found in the [Hydra documentation](https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/instantiate_objects/overview)).

There are many functions and I don't want to write them all out ... people have pointed out in similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631178/using-for-loop-to-define-multiple-functions-python) that modifying `globals()` for this purpose is bad practice. My use case is fairly constrained - documentation wise there is a one-one mapping (but obviously an IDE won't be able to resolve it).

Basically, I am wondering if there is a better way to do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your question related to [this](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1283) feature request and in particular to [this](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1283#issuecomment-757021697) comment?

FYI: In Hydra 1.1, [instantiate fully supports positional arguments](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/instantiate_objects/overview) so I think you should be able to call `functools.partial` directly without redefining it.

Comment: I added a simpler example for this that leverages the positional arguments support: https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1283#issuecomment-828956557