# How to make variables and functions that are attached on every single widget in for-loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, minecraft

I want to create **2D minecraft** test game. Got page with textures and so on... And then, I realized I need to create **25*25** map!

In this code below you will see, that I created **5 functions and 5 labels in for-loop** and if you are good at this language you will see I created **block breaking animation**. I'm going to care about holding animation after(if **you know** how to create holding animation **please let me know**)...

**Code you can test**:

```
from tkinter import *
tk=Tk()
tk.title('Minecraft 2D')
tk.config(bg='lightblue')
tk.resizable(False, False)
app_width=1500
app_height=750
screen_width=tk.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height=tk.winfo_screenheight()
x=(screen_width/2)-(app_width/2)
y=(screen_height/2)-(app_height/2)
tk.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
DestroyCounter=0
for i in range(10, 15):
    def Destroy1():
        global DestroyCounter
        if DestroyCounter==0:
            DestroyCounter=1
            GrassBlockSprite.config(bg='gray30')
        elif DestroyCounter==1:
            DestroyCounter=2
            GrassBlockSprite.config(bg='gray26')
        elif DestroyCounter==2:
            DestroyCounter=3
            GrassBlockSprite.config(bg='gray22')
        elif DestroyCounter==3:
            DestroyCounter=4
            GrassBlockSprite.config(bg='gray18')
        elif DestroyCounter==4:
            DestroyCounter=5
            GrassBlockSprite.place_forget()
    GrassBlockSprite=Canvas(tk, width=48, height=48, bg='brown', bd=0)
    GrassBlockSprite.place(relx=((i+0.2)/31.5), rely=0.305)
    GrassBlockSprite.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e:Destroy1())
tk.mainloop()
```

There just **last** block accepts animation, not other ones.
How to make this animation for **other blocks**? How to make variables and functions that **will not overlap** such as a loop in a **thread**? Do I need to create threads? But how to create them for **every block** in for loop? You can answer with just these **5 blocks** in code. You can fix code too if you want.

Comment: this code does not run. needs `tk.mainloop()` at the end.

Comment: it worked for me but I added it anyways.

Comment: function in for loop makes no sense as it writes to the same memory address 5 times. what is the intention of this ?

Comment: Do I need to create them in threads?

Comment: depending in wht you want to do,  yes.  or name each function differently `Destroy1`, `Destroy2`, `Destroy3` ...  `Destroyn`.

Comment: like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631178/using-for-loop-to-define-multiple-functions-python , although it would be considered pulluting the namespace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create different variable names while in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop)

Comment: You can have a list with the names of the various images, then do `...bg=destroyImages[DestroyCounter]` instead of that silly `if/elif` chain.  That would even let you change the number of steps.

Comment: And you don't really need a lambda.  You can just pass `Destroy1`.  It would have to accept the `e` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this as a replacement:

```
animation = ['gray30','gray26','gray22','gray18']

DestroyCounter=[]
GrassBlockSprite=[]

def Destroy(n):
    if DestroyCounter[n] < len(animation):
        GrassBlockSprite[n].config(bg=animation[DestroyCounter[n]])
    else:
        GrassBlockSprite[n].place_forget()
    DestroyCounter[n] += 1

for i in range(5):
    gbs=Canvas(tk, width=48, height=48, bg='brown', bd=0)
    gbs.place(relx=((i+10.2)/31.5), rely=0.305)
    gbs.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, i=i:Destroy(i))
    GrassBlockSprite.append(gbs)
    DestroyCounter.append(0)
```

Comment: The next step would be to create a `class Grass` that keeps all of this information.  It gets passed a starting X location.  Everything else can be internal.