# Create python function with name from array

Tags: python, arrays, function

I want to create functions (def $name:) where name comes from array=['str1', 'str2', ...].

I tried the code above and already searched on stackoverflow and google but did not find any solution.

```
array = ['String1', 'String2', ...]

def array[0]:

     code1

def array[1]:
     code2

String1()
String2()
```

Comment: @Axium it's not *impossible* it's simply **highly inadvisable**

Comment: Don't do this. Python != PHP and doesn't give you any great way to create variable variables. Just use a *container* like a list or a dict.

Comment: in addition to the dupe target, you can (and should) store functions in any datastructure: `[f1, f2]`

Comment: Kind of a fun question though :).

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a function using a variable.  But it turns out that you can rebind functions variable names.

See this post:
[How to use a variable as function name in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794634/how-to-use-a-variable-as-function-name-in-python)

Example of how to do that:

```
one = 'one'
two = 'two'
three = 'three'
l = [one, two, three]
def some_stuff():
    print("i am sure some stuff")
for item in l:
    def _f():
        some_stuff()
    globals()[item] = _f
    del _f

one()
two()
three()
```