# Unable to understand how function is being called in python

Tags: python, function

How is function (square,cube) being stored in operations variable. How function is being called here? How this code actually executes ?

```py
def square(n):
 return n**2

def cube(n): 
 return n**3
operations = [square, cube]
numbers = [2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29]
for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
      action = operations[i % 2]
      print(f"{action.__name__}({n}):", action(n))
```

Output:

```py
square(2): 4
cube(1): 1
square(3): 9
cube(4): 64
square(7): 49
cube(11): 1331
square(18): 324
cube(29): 24389
```

Comment: first of all, please try to make the code more readable by placing it under ``` (code ) ``` format.

Comment: Before posting its is readable.i don't know what happens how it changes everytime after posting it

Comment: Pease refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794634/how-to-use-a-variable-as-function-name-in-python

Comment: The call is at `action(n)`.

Comment: Then n**2 is returned to action(n)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part defines the functions `square` and `cube` and stores a reference for each function in the operations list.

```
def square(n):
 return n**2

def cube(n): 
 return n**3
operations = [square, cube]
```

The second part enumerates and loops through the numbers, using `square` when `i` is even, and `cube` when it's not.

```
numbers = [2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29]
for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
      action = operations[i % 2]
      print(f"{action.__name__}({n}):", action(n))
```

Comment: I wanna know that, is n**2 is returned to square which is in the operations list at first. And in the second part of the program, how action(n) prints 4 at first? Could you provide any site links to understand it better?

Comment: 1) action variable has function and has no parameter. 

2) i%2 returns 0 for 0,2,4... and 1 for 1,3,5 value of i. 

3) This means numbers[0], numbers[2] etc are used for square function, which is operations[0]

4) numbers[1], numbers[3] are used for cube function which is operations[1]. 


This is the reason, first SQUARE returned then CUBE returned then SQUARE returned then CUBE returned etc.,