# How can we define a function without using the `def` keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

It's possible to define a class without using the `class` keyword.
The following ...

```
get_i = lambda self: self.i    
get_i.__name__ = 'get_i'
get_i.__qualname__ = 'Klass2.get_i'
dct = dict(a=1, i=4, get_i=get_i)    
Klass2 = type('Klass2', (SuperK,), dct)
```

... produces the same end result as:

```
class Klass1(SuperK):
    a = 1
    i = 4
    def get_i(self):
        return self.i
```

How can we do something similar for functions? That is, how can we define a function without using the `def` or `lambda` keywords? What might a pure-python implementation of `dehf` look like if the following two pieces of code created identical `foo`s?

```
def foo(bar):
    bar += 934
    return bar

foo = dehf(blah, blah, blah, blah, [...])
```

Comment: You used `lambda` to define the function in the class. Why do you think you can define a function without `lambda`?

Comment: The use cases for creating a class with `type` are rather rare (like meta-classes). but why would you want to create a function without `def` or `lambda`?

Comment: Well I suppose if you want to make your code unmaintanable this might be a good idea. But IRL what good reason might you have to want to use such obtuse ways of defining a class or a function?

Comment: @Chris_Rands @barny One use-case is to create functions at with run-time-generated names. For example, suppose we want to create a function named `baz` at runtime, but we don't know that its going to be named `baz` when we write our code. As such, we can't simply write `def baz(*args):`. Maybe there's a decorator which outputs a function named, "`pretty_`<`foo`>," where <foo> is the function passed into the decorator. You can write, `func.__name__ = "pretty_" + foo.__name__`, but there are other use-cases for constructing functions without the `def`-keyword which aren't as easily dealt with.

Comment: If your question is about creating function names dynamically, then ask that question instead, you can still use `def` e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184281/python-dynamic-function-creation-with-custom-names Currently it feels like an XY problem

Answer (score 6):

You can create functions by calling the [`types.FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType) constructor. Keep in mind however that this constructor is undocumented and implementation specific. In CPython, we can figure out the constructor arguments by calling `help(types.FunctionType)`:

```
class function(object)
 |  function(code, globals[, name[, argdefs[, closure]]])
 |  
 |  Create a function object from a code object and a dictionary.
 |  The optional name string overrides the name from the code object.
 |  The optional argdefs tuple specifies the default argument values.
 |  The optional closure tuple supplies the bindings for free variables.
```

To create a code object, we can use [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile):

```
code = compile('print(5)', 'foo.py', 'exec')
function = types.FunctionType(code, globals())

function()  # output: 5
```

Comment: Interesting, but does this not feel like an XY problem, why would you do this?

Comment: @Chris_Rands No idea, you'd have to ask the OP. Maybe it's just simple curiosity :)

Comment: I have a use case, kind of. I have a module where I generate a set of functions at module scope. It works fine, except it totally confuses the IDE and code validation tools. So I needed to add a stub for each of the functions, and those stubs can be represented more compactly with something like your example.