# Get the display name dynamically inside Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model called person like this

```py
class person(models.Model):
    choice1 = ("a","DisplayNameA", "b", "DisplayNameB")
    choice1_field = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=choice1)
    choice2 = ("c","DisplayNameC", "d", "DisplayNameD")
    choice2_field = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=choice2)
    # and so on, there are many fields like these
```

After this, I am trying to generate a CSV file in my views

I can loop through all the fields I need and then access the values dynamically like this

```py
getattr(person_object, field_name)
```

However this returns "a", "b" and so on.

I know I can access the display name using `get_FOO_display()`, where foo is the field's name. However, as the retrieval of the field is happening dynamically, is there a way to access the display name of a field dynamically? Without having to [bind functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184281/python-dynamic-function-creation-with-custom-names)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass `get_fieldname_display` to the `getattr` function:

```
getattr(person_object, 'get_{}_display'.format(field_name))()
```

or you can make use of the [**`methodcaller`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) of the [**`operator`** package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html):

```
from operator import methodcaller

mygetter = methodcaller('get_{}_display'.format(field_name))

result = mygetter(person_object)
```

Comment: Python and its magic! That worked, thank you! So as per my understanding, the getattr function literally concats whatever I pass to the person_object "." followed by the field_name? Does it also mean that I can pass it arguments inside ```()```?

Comment: @SwetankPoddar: you obtain a method yes, so the `getattr(person_object, 'get_fieldname_display')` will result in `person_object.get_fieldname_display`, we then call that function, so *yes* you can pass arguments inside the parenthesis at the end :)

Comment: Willem there you are again, helping me out.  Thanks.